# LinkedIn API : How to display position of user

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm able to get a users profile using following code

```
IN.API.Profile("me")
.fields(["id", "firstName","lastName","positions:(company)"])
```

and displaying it in as HTML

```
.result(function(result) {
profile = result.values[0];
profHTML += "<h2 class=myname>" + profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName + "</a>;
$("#profile").html(profHTML);
```

but bit confused about how to display positions:(company) in the above code.  Please suggest.

Comment: `var positions = $.makeArray(profile.positions)` and iterate over the positions and add it to DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the returned JSON array of position values:

```
var positions = profile.positions;
var positionCount = positions._total;
for(var i = 0; i < positionCount; i++) {
  var company = positions.values[i].company;
  var title = positions.values[i].title;
  profHTML += "<div class="position">" + title + ", " + company.name + "</div>";
}
```

Note, that to pull the title from the [available positions data](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#positions), you'd need to indicate so in your initial query:

```
.fields('id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'positions:(title,company)')
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Mennega. That worked for me. 

However I just need the current company and position.  So, removed loop and simply called profile.positions.values[0].company and profile.positions.values[0].title

Hope this will help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

`var positions = $.makeArray(profile.positions)` and iterate over the positions and add it to DOM